# Whole page pop up message to be activated in line with alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website where it is able to successfully detect whether you are using Chrome as your browser and it works perfectly.

The coding for this "element" is -

```
var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
if(isChrome){
    alert("Chrome is detected");
}
```

The other element is a transparent whole page pop up message. This also works perfectly when using a HTML button to activate the message. But I need the pop up to be activated in Javascript not on a button click, I want it activated, in the line `alert("Chrome is detected");` up above. The coding for this element is below and you will see what I mean...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<style> 
.button{ width: 150px; padding: 10px; background-color: #FF8C00; box-shadow: -8px 8px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;
} 
#cover{ position:fixed; top:0; left:0; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); z-index:5; width:100%; height:100%; display:none;
} 
#loginScreen{ height:380px; width:340px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; z-index:10; display:none; background-color: white; no-repeat; border:5px solid #cccccc; border-radius:10px;
} 
#loginScreen:target, #loginScreen:target + #cover{ display:block; opacity:2;
}
.cancel{ display:block; position:absolute; top:3px; right:2px; background:rgb(245,245,245); color:black; height:32px; width:32px; font-size:30px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-radius:36px;
} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="top" align="center">

<!-- PLEASE DIRECT YOUR ATTENTION TO THE LINE BELOW -->
<a href="#loginScreen" class="button" id="thebutton">Click here to Log In</a> <!-- THIS IS HOW THE POP UP IS ACTIVATED BUT I NEED TO ACHIEVE THIS LINE IN JAVASCRIPT -->

</div>
<div id="loginScreen"> 
<span style="font-size:30px">Attention User!</span>
<a href="#" class="cancel" id="exitbutton">&times;</a>
</div>
<div id="cover" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How is the title related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to open your popup when detected func if true, change your code like this :

```
if(isChrome){
     // alert("Chrome is detected");
     $("#exitbutton").trigger('click'); //
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't do anything, PS: I don't use Jquery in my websites if I can help it, sorry.

Comment: Hi, you can use like this :                                                                          var el = document.getElementById('#exitbutton'); 
el.onclick();

Comment: But would I put in the .onclick(); to make the pop up disapper? @mehmetakifalp

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you will able to `trigger` `click` on an anchor tag with href.

You can use `window.location.href`

```
if(isChrome){
  var href = $('#thebutton').attr('href');
      window.location.href = href; 
    //alert("Chrome is detected");

}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/aoqL0d3j/)

Comment: When I removed the button because I don't want it anymore the whole thing stopped working

Comment: Maybe I could append a button that would somehow set the display of the #loginScreen and #cover to none but I tried and it didn't work however I reckon someone else might be able to do so

Comment: **I don't want it anymore** then how you will trigger it and on which element you want to add href attribute?

Comment: Something like appending a button. Then .setAttribute("html", "#");

Comment: Well this answer is based html & javascript that you have shared with the question & it works. If you need further modification please update your question or repost with final requirement